# how can i merge two partitions in two different servers in to one

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

I am using centos. I have having two servers with disk space 300 GB in each server. Is it possible to merge it and can be used as a single diskspace of 600gb

Comment: Are you trying to store one big file? Many small files? Need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: not necessarly a big file.. for my project setup if i can get both as single space i can use it without even checking diskspace upto 600gb. that is the intention

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for a distributed file system. Take a look at [GlusterFS](http://www.gluster.com/products/glusterfs/).